# Is there such a thing as a MSYS script file?

Tags: c, gtk, msys

I'm running MSYS under Windows and although it works I want to know if there is such a thing as a MSYS script file.

For example to compile a GTK program in C I need to type: `gcc source.c -o executable.exe 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0'` to compile.  Is there a way to store this in a file and run the file from MSYS without having to type in the command each time (IE like `.bat`, `.sh` files)?

Comment: MSYS should contain bash, so `.sh` files should work just fine.

Comment: for compilation in particular, you may also want to look at `make`...if your project might grow to involve multiple source files.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b  Thanks I will do that.  However I do a little more with MSYS than that (Python for example) but it's worth looking into.

Comment: BTW, just in case, you case use the search in history features of the shell. Just type Ctrl+R and a few letters of the command you typed that you want to call again. You can then press Ctrl+R several times to loop on different command matching that pattern. Another solution is the `!`  operator followed by a command, which will calls the last command you run that matches in your history. In your case `!gcc` will run your whole gcc command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to automate building an application, just use a build system. The [Meson build system](http://mesonbuild.com) is what the GTK+ developers recommend now (and GStreamer, and many other projects). It's multiplatform, and available as a package in MSYS2 (I used it there, works like a charm). They have a [simple Meson tutorial](http://mesonbuild.com/Tutorial.html) where they build a GTK application. That's 3 lines of code.